# A-B Test - clean random distribution

Tags: marketing-cloud, test-setup

I´d like to use the AB Test function in the Email Studio.

I´ve got one big sending data extension. That DE contains all subsrcibers from different countries. Now I want to test 2 different subjecttypes (10% vs. 10% --> 80% winner send). The international content is placed in a content DE connected via amp.
Is there a chance to ensure equal test distribution in the countries?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Not via the AB Test function.  This will take the DE and randomly separate it into the 3 containers - it will not take into account any other attributes.

For instance you could have 60% of your Russia emails inside the 10% and then 30% in second 10% leaving only 10% in your 80% remainder.

What you would need to do is to use SQL queries to pull these percentages out while ensuring equal country distribution.

The issue with this is that the AB Test would then have to be completely manual or would require a good amount of custom scripting to automate.